# Is it possible to edit the structure of a site through Craft CMS?

Tags: html, web, craftcms

I'm helping a nonprofit do some edits to their site because they had originally asked a digital agency to create it but they handed it over with some tiny bugs like missing links, repeated navbar items, misalignment in grid, etc. The only thing I have access to is the Craft CMS the website operates with...and the agency is saying I can fix these kinds of bugs through the CMS.....Am I just dumb and are these actual changes I can do through Craft or is this agency being incompetent and terrible at communication?

Answer (score 0):

If you download the correct plugins yes. It depends how they have setup the admin area and how much control they have actually given you. Missing links and repeated nav bar items should be I  entries & repeated entries in terms of style miss alignment could just be text alignment and that's also in entries. If you have no experience just mess around until you break something then call them and tell them it broke.

Answer (score 0):

This thing totally depends on how the website is set up like the admin area the entries and page structure if they are set up with neo structures and you don't have any experience then things can go wrong so better you should go for some experts so they can manage things without any hassle.